# Replace specific criteria once

Tags: excel, vba, replace, constants

been learning VBA and it's already helped 10 fold with the projects I'm working on.

I've hit a snag though.

Right now I currently have a "template table", which has formulas built into it.

It looks something like this:

```
Name
Date  Revenue   Cost  profit  margin
8/08  $10,000   $5000 $5000   100%

Total xxx       xxx    xxx
```

So when I have a new name to add, I copy that whole "template table" and paste it below the last cells used (I looped to find the last cell, so this is labeled endRow).  Inside the 8/08 date row (for revenue/cost) I have an indirect formula, so I lookup the 'Name' within the sheet name 8/08 (I label the sheet names the date).

I need to keep the 'Name' a constant so it's $A$20 for that whole box. As I add new dates, it stays $A$20, while the other formulas change as I insert the dates (IE references the date directly to the left).

This is what I've been doing to replace the formula. Only issue is, if my template is in cell $A$9, and I go to replace the 9 to say 25, if the formula for the date tab is say 19, it changes the 19 to 125.  So it's changing all the 9's to 25. I just want to change the formula that was $A$fn but I get an error doing that.

fn = my for loop to discover where the template box is. So I'm replacing that original formula with the new cell that I pasted it to

```
Range(Cells(endRow + 2, 2), Cells(endRow + 2, 7)).Replace What:=fn,    Replacement:=endRow, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

So the question is, how to change $A$x (x being the cell #) to $A$y (the new cell #) and not touching Ax.

```
    For fn = 1 To 10000
    Set networkCell = Cells(fn, 1)
        If networkCell.Value = "New Station Template" Then
            Range(Cells(fn, 1), Cells(fn + 5, 10)).Copy
            Range(Cells(endRow, 1), Cells(endRow + 5, 10)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Cells(endRow, 1).Value = "New Station"
            Range(Cells(endRow + 2, 2), Cells(endRow + 2, 7)).Replace What:=fn, Replacement:=endRow, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
            count = count + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I've tried: 
////    .Replace What:="$A$" & fn /////
But that doesn't work, I get an error of sorts

Comment: I wonder if I did a newVariable = "$A$" & fn, instead of using fn to replace, I use newVariable. Since it doesn't look like you can create $A$fn.

Comment: other option is to use named ranges instead of address for fixed locations.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new variable to combine the constraints $A$ to the cell #, seems to work compared to trying to combine $A$ and the cell # within the replace code.

```
    For fn = 1 To 10000
    Set networkCell = Cells(fn, 1)
        If networkCell.Value = "New Station Template" Then
            Range(Cells(fn, 1), Cells(fn + 5, 10)).Copy
            Range(Cells(endRow, 1), Cells(endRow + 5, 10)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Cells(endRow, 1).Value = "New Station"
            oldForm = “$A$” & fn
            newForm = “$A$” & endRow
            Range(Cells(endRow + 2, 2), Cells(endRow + 2, 7)).Replace What:= oldForm, Replacement:= newForm,  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

            count = count + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```